# Ajax call within form causes posting of form

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im using MVC5. My cshtml uses

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SmurfNewDisaplay", "Kombak"))
{
}
```

to submit to the method SmurfNewDisaplay in the Kombak controller. 
I have a link within the form that i want to make an ajax call and get a Json response. But when i click this link the form seems to be posted. Here is the Ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Kombak/GetKombaksByJson",
            error: getFriendsError
        }).done(function (data) {

            createKombakList(data);
        });
```

And here is the markup and HTML: http://pastebin.com/YncP5cfe.

So when i make the ajax Json call i get an error in return and then im redirected to /Kombak/SmurfNewDisaplay

I need the ajax call to return the json response and then the submit button to post to the action.

Answer (score 1):

I think the link is followed. 
You should use a e.preventDefault(); within your .click(e) function